# Countdown Timer not refreshing

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown timer on my website and it counts down in seconds (don't want minutes, hours, days, etc.)

The timer works and shows up as I want it to when the date is added into the variable, the only issue I'm having is that `setInterval()` is not refreshing it every second like it is supposed to. If I remove the php value from `var now = Date().getTime();` if the time is higher than 2 hours, it cuts the timer in half but `setInterval()` refreshes it so I'm at a loss lol

Here is my code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $newDate; ?>").getTime(); 
  var x = setInterval(function() { 
  var now = new Date("<?php echo $dateNow; ?>").getTime(); 
  var distance = countDownDate - now; 
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * "<?php echo $time; ?>")) / 1000); 
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = seconds + " s "; 
    console.log('tick');
  if (distance < 0) {
   clearInterval(x);
   document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Finished";
  }
 }, 1000);
</script>

<?php
    $date="2018-11-16 15:32:16"; // This date comes from the database
    $time="7200"; // Adds 7200 Seconds to date
    $dateinsec=strtotime($date);
    $new=$dateinsec+$time;
    $newDate=date('M d, Y  H:i:s', $new);
    $dateNow=Date('M d, Y H:i:s');
?>

<p id="timer"></p>
```

Comment: Josh, you need to initialize the php variables before you use them, but it would be more readable if your js used js variables and just set the value of the variables from your php before the logic.

Comment: They are initialized before i use them on my site, putting them on here put them below the javascript for some reason.  I have a hastebin with the code as well

https://hastebin.com/duretifafa.xml

This was the previous version that was a little more messy, ive been working on this for a few days now lol

Comment: Cool, then the position of the PHP is not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten your code to place the php variables at the top using more obvious and verbose variable names. I may have messed up the algorithm but hopefully this helps.

```js
/*
<?php
    $date="2018-11-16 15:32:16"; // This date comes from the database
    $countdown_date = strtotime( $date ); // convert that date to seconds
    $added_time = "7200"; // Seconds we'll add to date
    $countdown_date += $added_time; // countdown_date is now the date + added_time in seconds
    $countdown_date *= 1000; // now countdown_date is in milliseconds
?>

const countDownDate = <?php echo $countdown_date; ?>;
*/

const countDownDate = 1542418336000;

const x = setInterval(function() {
  const differenceInMillis = countDownDate - Date.now();
  const differenceInSeconds = Math.floor( differenceInMillis / 1000 );

  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = differenceInSeconds + "s";
  if (differenceInMillis < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Finished";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="timer"></p>
```

Comment: This just returns "Finished" and doesnt show a timer.

Comment: When I execute the PHP code at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6394feba1e7db2843561469fa605f9d613e64318 I get 1542418336000. When I press Run Code Snippet here I get a countdown timer in Chrome, IE, and Firefox. Can you verify what you are getting from your PHP is after "now" or see if you have any JS errors in the dev console?

Comment: Ive gotten it working, it seems to work flawless now, the issue was in some of the php, forgot  few values.  Thanks a ton!  Quick addition now that this is working i can move forward to the next thing.  I want to add a database update into the following area ONLY when the timer hits 0. I noticed adding the PHP and then refreshing the page will automatically set this to "Finished" instead of keeping the timer running.  https://hastebin.com/babaqelace.pl